# How to prove that if $A$ is infinite and $B$ is finite, then $|A\cup B|=|A|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm studying logic and unfortunately, I'm a newbie at this, so I don't see the stuff everyone sees at the moment. I want to solve following exercise, but get nowhere:

> Let $A$ be an infinite set and let $B$ be a finite set. Use the AC to
>   prove that $|A| +|B| = |A|$.

I've proved this one though:

> If $X$ is an infinite set, there is an injective function $\mathbb{N}
>  \rightarrow X$, hence $\omega \leq |X|$.

But I don't see how I could use this. What's the logic here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use your second theorem.  Suppose that $f: \Bbb N \to A$ is an injection.  Let $S  = f(\Bbb N) \subset A$.  Let $g:B \to \{1,\dots,|B|\}\subset \Bbb N$ be a map enumerating the elements of $B$.

We can now define the map $\phi:A \coprod B \to A$ by

$$
\phi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x \in A \setminus S\\
f(f^{-1}(x) + |B|) & x \in S\\
f(g(x)) & x \in B
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I understand your answer. However, how can we prove it is a bijection?